# How to make a Collection of Objects case in-sensitive?

Tags: java, collections, lucene, indexing

I have two classes as follows;

```
Class ABC{
    private String location;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private Food category;
    .................
    .................

   // getters

   // setters
}


Class XYZ{

   public Collection<ABC> filterInput(String input){
       Collection<ABC> result = new HashSet<ABC>();
       if (criteria != null) {
            try {
                Analyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();

                // Now search the index:
                IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);

                // Parse a simple query that searches for "text":
                QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]{Index.CATEGORY.name(), Index.CITY.name(), Index.NAME.name()}, analyzer);
                Query query = parser.parse(criteria) ;
                TopDocCollector collector = new TopDocCollector(500);
                isearcher.search(query, collector );

                // Iterate through the results:
                ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
                for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) {
                        Document document = isearcher.doc(hit.doc);
                        ABC entry = cache.get(Integer.valueOf(document.get(Index.OBJECT.name())));
                        results.add(entry);
            }
                 isearcher.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { }

}
```

**Was curious am I missing something here?**

**Any help/recommendations would be appreciated.**

Comment: What do you want to do with collection elements? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexanderGavrilov With the collection elements I will be searching/Parsing it and performing some similar operations on it.

Comment: I like your toUpperCase() idea

Comment: What you mean about insensitive, about when you add to a collection an item?

Comment: @RobertBeltran Thanks... But I am looking for is there a way to make the COllection case insensitive? I know about CaseInsecsitiveHashMap, but not sure for HashSet....

Comment: We know that `HashSet` use `equals` and `hashCode` if you override equals with lowerCase in `ABC` you are saying that a `ABC` with `city= NEW YORK` is the same as `city = new York` and perhaps you don't want that! It's better idea to make your own wrapper collection insenstive or make a wrapper class to `ABC` an `InsensitiveABC`

Comment: @JNL NO, it's not right cause your collection is about `ABC` not Strings, and if you make a `TreeSet<ABC>` Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface

Comment: Ah, I'd probably just extend the collection then or through composition wrap one and to the toUpperCase() on the put()/add() calls

Comment: @nachokk another solution `Solution 2` I thought of was making the Class ABC implement comparable so that if I have a Collection as a TreeSet it would serve my purpose. Any suggestions about this approach?

Comment: Guys, just an update... I was in the wrong direction, I believe I will have to use lucene, in the QueryParse here, to get the Case Insensitive fields. Am new to this, so any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks for all the prior help, @nachokk

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `hashcode`  and `equals` of the `ABC` class in case insensitive manner
For example

```
int hashcode = 31*location.toUpperCase().hashcode();
```

And for the `equals` method you can use case insensitive equals for strings : `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)`

But you can still persist them in whatever way you want

Comment: You are right, with implementing `hashCode` and `equals` method, but I am looking more into implementing the Collection as CaseInsensitive than modifying the class ABC.

Comment: -1 That's not a good idea at all, cause he don't want to say that an object is equal to other one with insensitive way. You are modifying the class

Comment: I doub that it's possible, because the different collections does not know about anything of the internal working of the classes, and for a good reason - because they will be dependent on the implementation of the classes you put in them --> they will not be universal

Comment: @nachokk he didn't say the opposite either :)

Comment: That's true i will remove my downvote, but i still think this is not what he want,therefore  is not a solution.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev nachokk is right, I am not looking to modify class ABC, but only have the `Collection results` as a case insensitive. But thanks for your help and comments Svetlin.

Comment: @JNL Do you need the collection to be generic -> i.e. to be able to store elements from classes different from `ABC` ?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev No. Class ABC need not be generic. Did not understand how would that help?

Comment: I was not asking about the `ABC` class, but about the `case insensitive collection`

Answer (score 0):

Having your setters apply either upperCase or lowerCase would work. Another possibility is to implement Comparable and have the equals method use equalsIgnoreCase.